# Find and add to all floats

Tags: replace, sed, awk, grep

This is probably a very simple problem, but I was wondering how to find all floats in a file and surround them by some text, e.g.

Input file:

```
input1 & X & Y & Z \\
input2 & ...
```

Output file:

```
input1 & float(X) & float(Y) & float(Z) \\
input2 & ...
```

I was thinking about using sed or awk, but I don't see how the found float can be reused in the replaced string.

Comment: Is it a plain text file?

Comment: No, it are csv's and tsv's.

Comment: hw bout finding (dot) to identify the float???

Comment: pls give some input example, who knows apart from X,Y,Z are there other text? and are X Y and Z all float numbers separated by `tab`? or `,` or space? example pls

Comment: This can be done using `awk` with `gsub()`. This [answer from unix.stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25122/how-to-use-regex-with-awk-for-string-replacement) should be able to help you.

Comment: I added some more context to the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dirty and quick with sed:

```
kent$  echo "input1 & 3.5 & 0.5 & 3.55"|sed 's/[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+/float(&)/g'
input1 & float(3.5) & float(0.5) & float(3.55)
```

Comment: what about echo "input1.2 & 3 & 0.5", must insure ther is no other char than "space" around

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk '{$3="float("$3")";$5="float("$5")";$7="float("$7")"}1' file
input1 & float(X) & float(Y) & float(Z) \\
```

This just replace based on position.

Comment: Does awk have list comprehension (so that I just can specify a list of indices)?

Comment: you had a "typo" in your output, you typed the output, didn't you? :D

Comment: It can be based on numbers, like the Kent post, number of fields. Or any other way you like.  Does the pattern repeat, is it only number, are fields on the same place all the time etc.  All this info may create different solutions.